# Add 4 spaces in the middle of the code

Tags: support, code, indentation

I know that if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> I automatically can add 4 spaces, but what if the code has already 4 spaces and I need to add 4 spaces more to it?

If I press <kbd>tab</kbd> in the SO editor it just gets me down in the page. It often happens that I have to edit a question that has bad indentation, like this code snippet example (casual, purely invented):

```
void foo()
{
printf("I haven't understood how to indent well");
}
```

So in this case how do I add 4 spaces to the printf line?

Do I have to cut-paste it to an editor or I can do it on the SO editor?

Comment: I delete one character at the beginning of the block, select it, press ctrl-k and then re-add the missing space to the first line as a "minimal key press" strategy.

Comment: But if I have a block of code of 30 lines I have to do it 30 times, and I'm lazy :)

Comment: I do pull the code into an editor, but the SO editor knowing how to fix indentation would be pretty cool

Comment: Do it beforehand in a code editor.

Comment: @Chichiray "it often happens that I have to edit a question that has bad indentation"

Comment: @Michael: oh right. In extreme cases (more than, say, 10 lines) I just copypaste to Eclipse, Ctrl+Shift+F and copypaste back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have indented code

```
lo
rem
ip
sum
```

(just much longer) and you want to indent a bunch of consecutive lines.

Place a random letter at the start of the first line you want to indent further,

```
lo
a    rem
    ip
sum
```

select the lines you want to indent, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, and delete the random letter.

Answer (score 2):

There is [some browser script](https://stackapps.com/q/3247/5198), which is described thus:

> This user script changes the behavior of a few keys (most notably the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key) within the post editor to behave more like it does in IDEs or text editors.

Me loves it.